# Webpack 4 creates multiple vendor files for each dynamic import

Tags: javascript, webpack

I use the following code to import a vendor file in Webpack 4:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    import(
        /* webpackChunkName: "brace_modes" */
        /* webpackMode: "lazy" */
        /* webpackPrefetch: true */
        './brace_modes'
    );
}, 0);
```

The brace_modes.js file is:

```
import 'brace/mode/c_cpp';
import 'brace/mode/csharp';
import 'brace/mode/css';
import 'brace/mode/html';
import 'brace/mode/java';
import 'brace/mode/javascript';
import 'brace/mode/json';
import 'brace/mode/plain_text';
```

My issue is that when I compile, Webpack creates 2 separate files for this import like:

brace_modes.eaf5fc4fecd3199ea30d.js
vendors~brace_modes.eaf5fc4fecd3199ea30d.js

This results in 2 separate files being loaded at runtime by the browser, hurting performance. This is new behavior in Webpack 4; I didn't see it happen when using Webpack 2. How can I tell Webpack to not use a separate `vendors~` file?

As I'm aware, I haven't changed the configuration for this in webpack.config.js in any way.

Comment: I think `webpackMode: "eager"` instead of `lazy` will help!

Comment: That just results in the entire `brace_modes` file being included in `app.<hash>.js`. I'd like `brace_modes` to be a separate file.

Comment: Configure the [splitChunks](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/).

Comment: @emix I'm trying to avoid polluting my `webpack.config` with specific information about imports. Is it possible for me to do this via a comment config param? Could you also post your comment as an answer?